# Sign in with twitter error

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am new to twitter API and I am using the Abraham Williams PHP twitter library to oauth user and sign in.

```
    require_once ("twitteroauth.php");

    /* Build TwitterOAuth object with client credentials. */
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth($this->consumer_key, $this->consumer_secret);

    /* Get temporary credentials. */
    $request_token = $connection->getRequestToken($this->callback);

    /* Save temporary credentials to session. */
    $this->session->set_userdata('oauth_token', $request_token['oauth_token']);
    $this->session->set_userdata('oauth_token_secret', $request_token['oauth_token_secret']);

    /* If last connection failed don't display authorization link. */
    switch ($connection->http_code)
    {
        case 200:
            $url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($request_token['oauth_token'], TRUE);
            header('Location: ' . $url);
            break;

        default:
            echo 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
    }
```

But I always get an error the message "Could not connect to twitter' and I'm not redirected to the twitter oauth page. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure your consumer key and secret are correct? May also be helpful to `echo $connection->http_code` and see what it is.

Comment: Aren't the tokens provided by twitter when I make the request?

Comment: Sorry I meant the consumer key and consumer secret. Edited my comment but not in time it would appear.

Comment: Yes they are correct, no problem there.

Comment: How about the http_code, what is getting returned?

Comment: 401 Could not connect to Twitter

Comment: I'm a bit suprised about your usage of $this. Your provided snipplet does not seem to be in class context. If this is true, change your $this lines to another context, if not, please provide the rest of the code.

Comment: It's OK I figured out the problem. I hadn't provided with a callback url in the app settings and twitter saw this as a desktop app instead of a web app.

Comment: Florian, you should post that as an answer so it can be accepted. It's valueable info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I hadn't provided with a callback url in the app settings and twitter saw this as a desktop app instead of a web app.